# C 'for' loop is only looping once

Tags: c, cs50

I scoured through the code for the 'for' loop issues here. I checked my semicolons etc,but still cannot figure out why my loop is only looping once.

Code is shown below, Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("Enter Height: ");
    int height = GetInt();
    int i;
    int count = 1;

    for(i=height; i>0; i--)
        {
        for(i=height-1;i>0;i--)
            {
                printf(" ");
            }    
        for(i=count;i>0;i--)
            {
                printf("#");
            }
        printf("  ");
        for(i=count;i>0;i--)
            {
                printf("#");
            }

            count++;
            printf("\n");
        }
}
```

Comment: What is `GetInt` return value in your test?

Comment: You're using `i` in all those loops, I think that might cause it.

Comment: Use different names for the control variables that are nested

Comment: what indent style is this?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: It is [Whitesmith's Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Whitesmiths_style).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it's not Whitesmith's because you can see the `printf`s are one more level down while in Whitesmith's the child level is equal to the brackets

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc : Ah, OK.   There's a GNU style that has the body of the loop more indented than the braces which are themselves more indented than the controlling statement.  It's not a common style, though (or, at least, I've seldom seen it in the wild).  I prefer Allman, but one of the 1TBS styles is OK too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the same iterator in the inner loops, while it's being used in the outer(main) one.

Just use an integer called `j` (declare it earlier of course) and use it in the inner one.

Comment: Thanks, new to C, had no idea the iterators read outside the for loops parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `i` in inner loop. That is causing the problem because the inner loop will make it `0`. So after the first iteration condition, the outer loop will stop looping.

Use a different variable in the inner loop to overcome the problem.
Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int height;
    int i,j;
    int count = 1;
    printf("Enter Height: ");
    scanf("%d",&height);
    for(i=height; i>0; i--)
        {
        for(j=height-1;j>0;j--)
            {
                printf(" ");
            }    
        for(j=count;j>0;j--)
            {
                printf("#");
            }
        printf("  ");
        for(j=count;j>0;j--)
            {
                printf("#");
            }

            count++;
            printf("\n");
        }
}
```